# hasOne does not deliver users and profiles

Tags: cakephp-3.x, has-one

When I want retrieve my users, I have no profiles.
I setted up my database along the convention.

I got the following code in my model (UserTable):

```
<?php
// src/Model/Table/UsersTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->hasOne('Profiles')
          ->setDependent(true);
    }
}
```

My Controller is this:

```
<?php
// src/Controller/UsersController.php

namespace App\Controller;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash'); // Include the FlashComponent
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $query = $this->Users->find();
        $results = $query->all();
        $this->set(compact('results'));
    }
}
```

After call index, I get all my users, which is a good thing. But there are no profiles.
I think, I missed a line of code somewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the `contain` thing. In cakephp 2, it was not needed.

The controller code is now this (it's working):

```
$query = $this->Users->find();
$query->contain(['Profiles']);
$results = $query->all();
```

thanks anyway.